# IDA Pro S12X flash page references

Tags: ida, motorola

Trying to analyse a dump from MC9S12X series MCU and can`t get how IDA making cross flash page references and if it could be done without scripts.

The project contains 64 code segments with linear addresses 0x700000, 0x704000,  etc. Every segment`s head points to flash window with virtual address 0x8000. When I try to make automatic analysis all CALL/branch instructions points to the current segment. How could I assign any segment a page number?

Comment: Questdiono, did you proceed on this in any way?

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30394/how-can-ida-pro-disassemble-paged-memory-from-hcs12-processort

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to do some reverse engineering with an MC9S12X.

What i know is that it uses PPAGE register at 0x0030 of local address space to the which 16k page is shown at 0x8000.

IDA has concept of segments, so it may be able to emulate the paging of the CPU.

There are branch instructions that may be able to also load a specific segment.